# in place sort returns None for empty list

Tags: python

Why is it that `[].sort() != []` but instead `[].sort() = None`?

Logically, it seems that the first case should be true.

Comment: The answer is in your question. It's an _in place sort_. It's not supposed to return anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "return list.sort()" return None, not the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list)

Answer (score 19):

It's because `sort` always returns `None`, it's an in-place sort. Use `sorted` instead.

```
>>> sorted([]) == []
True
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because lists are mutable. `[].sort()` doesn't return a new list, it just changes the existing one, so the return value is nothing, or `None`. It's the same reason when you go to sort, you don't have to do something like `list = list.sort()`, you just do `list.sort()`

Answer (score 2):

The Python docs cover this in at least two distinct places:

> The `sort()` and `reverse()` methods modify the list in place for economy
>   of space when sorting or reversing a large list. To remind you that
>   they operate by side effect, they don’t return the sorted or reversed
>   list.

- [note 7 under Mutable Sequence Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

> You can also use the `list.sort()` method of a list. It modifies the
>   list in-place (and returns None to avoid confusion). Usually it’s less
>   convenient than `sorted()` - but if you don’t need the original list,
>   it’s slightly more efficient.

- [Sorting Basics under the HOWTO on sorting](http://docs.python.org/howto/sorting.html#sorting-basics)