# Why does "return list.sort()" return None, not the list?

Tags: python

I've been able to verify that the `findUniqueWords` does result in a sorted `list`. However, it does not return the list. Why?

```
def findUniqueWords(theList):
    newList = []
    words = []

    # Read a line at a time
    for item in theList:

        # Remove any punctuation from the line
        cleaned = cleanUp(item)

        # Split the line into separate words
        words = cleaned.split()

        # Evaluate each word
        for word in words:

            # Count each unique word
            if word not in newList:
                newList.append(word)

    answer = newList.sort()
    return answer
```

Comment: I don't think you need to turn item into a string so many times. Once is normally enough and it's cleaner to do it on the input to cleanUp as well.

Comment: Just a silly thought, but if you want a list of unique items, why don't you just convert into a set? You can then convert them back to a list if you need.

`theSet= set(theList)`

And you are done, you only need to cast it back to  list: 

`theList = list(theSet)`

Done. Easy.

Comment: Adding to what @runlevel0 said (which is a good idea): You can convert a `theSet' into a sorted list with `sorted(theSet)`.

Comment: very irregular language

Comment: This is a core - but *problematic/irritating* - philosophical choice of the language. Chaining in general is an orphaned concept in python.

Comment: @StephenBoesch: It's not just to discourage chaining (though that's part of it), it's to avoid confusion over whether a method returns a new copy with the change applied, or mutates in place (if `list.sort` returned a `list`, is it the original `list` mutated in place, or a new one?). Python built-ins stick to one or the other; methods on immutable types like `str` *do* chain (they can't mutate in place, so they return a new object with the mutation applied), while most methods on mutable types like `list` don't. But for common cases like this, `sorted` exists to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: @ShadowRanger  No disagreement on why python has broken the chainability and its "avoid confusion".  But those are poor design choices for the language.  I end up having to write helper methods to band-aid  these **return nothing** methods.   Various functionals libraries partially fill this gap including one i put into pypi  `infixpy`. But for some projects there are restrictions to only use core python and numpy/pandas.   It is a serious problem for me that this super popular language is so weak for functionals programming ( for comprehensions only reasonably handle two levels of nesting).

Comment: Just because chaining is a common API idiom in one language doesn't mean it it must be in every language, and it has very little to do with functional programming (which encourages the use of immutable values, which makes the question of mutating method returning a reference to the object moot).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't sort my list because it is NoneType? Simple Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668154/cant-sort-my-list-because-it-is-nonetype-simple-python)

Comment: In JS, chainable in-place methods like `.reverse()` and `.sort()` tend to create unexpected bugs when used alongside the rest of the array methods that don't modify their arguments, like `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, etc. Returning void is common practice for any language when a method is in-place, like Java's `Collections.sort()`, PHP's `sort` or C++'s `std::sort()`. JS is the exception here, while Python is in keeping with the standard. Maybe Ruby is clearest with the `sort!` and `sort` in-place vs not idiom.

Comment: Question for mods: Why was this marked as duplicate rather than the other question, which was asked later and has fewer views answers and upvotes?

Answer (score 364, accepted):

`list.sort` sorts the list in place, i.e. it doesn't return a new list. Just write

```
newList.sort()
return newList
```

Comment: `return sorted(newList)` is shorter. Doesn't matter here since the variable is local, but in-place sort could change a shared variable in some cases.

Comment: It's interesting that if an entry is added to a list, either `a.append('x')`, or `a.extend('x)` you can't chain `sort()` on the end either.  It has to be split into 2 lines. It would have been nicer had the methods returned the list!  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html  This same message bit me by doing just that. Consequently you have to break the thing into two lines, You have to use `.sort()` **NOT** `sorted()` on the list afterwards, since this generates the same error  `l = ['1']; l = sorted(l.append('2'))` (I just added semi-colon so you could cut/paste and run)

Comment: I'd also add it may be worth look at this: http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/ , https://github.com/grantjenks/python-sortedcontainers In my, was already thinking of refactoring from a list to a set, since I didn't want duplicates, and was then looking for a SortedSet implementation, and didn't find one in collections module... Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953205/why-are-there-no-sorted-containers-in-pythons-standard-libraries

Comment: **Why** was `sort` function designed this way? is there any performance overhead or other drawbacks if return the sorted list instead of None?

Comment: I also faced the folowing problem : `print(newList.sort())` gave `None`. However when i did, `newList.sort()` and then `print(newList)` it worked.

Comment: @LeiYang: Pop quiz: If I do `b = a.sort()`, then `b.pop()`, what is the effect on `a`? In some languages, `.sort` returns a copy of `a` that has been sorted, in others, it sorts in-place and returns a reference to `a`. Python removes ambiguity by having in-place mutation return `None`, not an alias to the thing they were called on, so there's less confusion. You use `sorted` if you need a copy (and it works on all iterables, not just `list`, consistently returning a `list` in sorted order). There'd be roughly zero performance overhead to `alist.sort()` returning `alist`, just uncertainty.

Comment: To be clear, obviously, the Python approach still leads to confusion (as seen here). But it's usually confusion over something going *obviously* wrong, close to the point where the error was made. In another language, you'd have *silent* misbehavior that might not manifest until long after the error occurred.

Answer (score 233):

The problem is here:

```
answer = newList.sort()
```

`sort` does not return the sorted list; rather, it sorts the list in place.

Use:

```
answer = sorted(newList)
```

Comment: This is what most will need: difference between `list.sort()` and `sorted(list)`.

Comment: Refer this doc for more detail - https://realpython.com/python-sort/

Answer (score 69):

[Here is an email](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/038855.html) from Guido van Rossum in Python's dev list explaining why he choose not to return `self` on operations that affects the object and don't return a new one.

> This comes from a coding style (popular in various other languages, I
>     believe especially Lisp revels in it) where a series of side effects
>     on a single object can be chained like this:
>
> ```
>  x.compress().chop(y).sort(z)
> ```
>
> which would be the same as
>
> ```
>   x.compress()
>   x.chop(y)
>   x.sort(z)
> ```
>
> I find the chaining form a threat to readability; it requires that the
>       reader must be intimately familiar with each of the methods.  The
>       second form makes it clear that each of these calls acts on the same
>       object, and so even if you don't know the class and its methods very
>       well, you can understand that the second and third call are applied to
>       x (and that all calls are made for their side-effects), and not to
>       something else.
>
> I'd like to reserve chaining for operations that return new values,
>       like string processing operations:
>
> ```
>  y = x.rstrip("\n").split(":").lower()
> ```

Comment: Amusingly, `split(":").lower()` is a bad chain because `split` returns a list that doesn't have a `lower` method.

Answer (score 31):

Python has two kinds of sorts: a sort *method* (or "member function") and a sort *function*. The sort method operates on the contents of the object named -- think of it as *an action that the object is taking to re-order itself*. The sort function is an *operation over the data represented by an object* and returns a new object with the same contents in a sorted order.

Given a list of integers named `l` the list itself will be reordered if we call `l.sort()`:

```
>>> l = [1, 5, 2341, 467, 213, 123]
>>> l.sort()
>>> l
[1, 5, 123, 213, 467, 2341]
```

This method has no return value. But what if we try to assign the result of `l.sort()`?

```
>>> l = [1, 5, 2341, 467, 213, 123]
>>> r = l.sort()
>>> print(r)
None
```

`r` now equals actually nothing. This is one of those weird, somewhat annoying details that a programmer is likely to forget about after a period of absence from Python (which is why I am writing this, so *I* don't forget again).

The function `sorted()`, on the other hand, will not do anything to the contents of `l`, but will return a new, sorted list with the same contents as `l`:

```
>>> l = [1, 5, 2341, 467, 213, 123]
>>> r = sorted(l)
>>> l
[1, 5, 2341, 467, 213, 123]
>>> r
[1, 5, 123, 213, 467, 2341]
```

Be aware that the returned value is *not* a [deep copy](http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php), so be cautious about side-effecty operations over elements contained within the list as usual:

```
>>> spam = [8, 2, 4, 7]
>>> eggs = [3, 1, 4, 5]
>>> l = [spam, eggs]
>>> r = sorted(l)
>>> l
[[8, 2, 4, 7], [3, 1, 4, 5]]
>>> r
[[3, 1, 4, 5], [8, 2, 4, 7]]
>>> spam.sort()
>>> eggs.sort()
>>> l
[[2, 4, 7, 8], [1, 3, 4, 5]]
>>> r
[[1, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 17):

Python habitually returns `None` from functions and methods that mutate the data, such as `list.sort`, `list.append`, and `random.shuffle`, with the idea being that it hints to the fact that it was mutating.

If you want to take an iterable and return a new, sorted list of its items, use the `sorted` builtin function.

Answer (score 11):

A small piece of wisdom which I didn't see in other answers:

All methods for mutable objects in python (like lists) which modify the list return `None`. So, for lists this also includes list.append(), list.reverse(), etc. That's why the syntax should be

`myList.sort()`

Meanwhile, methods for any immutable object (like strings) must be assigned like so:

`myString = myString.strip()`

Comment: Exactly my problem. If you're using a lambda, use sorted instead

Answer (score 9):

To understand why it does not return the list:

sort() doesn't return any value while the sort() *method* just sorts the elements of a given list in a specific order - *ascending* or *descending* without returning any value.

So problem is with `answer = newList.sort()` where answer is none.

Instead you can just do `return  newList.sort()`.

The syntax of the sort() method is:

```
list.sort(key=..., reverse=...)
```

Alternatively, you can also use Python's in-built function sorted() for the same purpose.

```
sorted(list, key=..., reverse=...)
```

Note: The simplest difference between sort() and sorted() is: sort() doesn't return any value while, sorted() returns an iterable list.

So in your case `answer = sorted(newList)`.

Comment: > Instead you can just do return  newList.sort()...... is misleading. It will return None not the sorted list. So yes you can do it but will probably not do what was intended.

Answer (score 5):

> you can use sorted() method if you want it to return the sorted list.
>   It's more convenient.

```
l1 = []
n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
  user = int(input())
  l1.append(user)
sorted(l1,reverse=True)
```

> list.sort() method modifies the list in-place and returns None.

if you still want to use sort you can do this.

```
l1 = []
n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
  user = int(input())
  l1.append(user)
l1.sort(reverse=True)
print(l1)
```