# Can't sort my list because it is NoneType? Simple Python

Tags: python, list, nonetype

I get this error when I try to figure out the low and high prices for my BeautifulSoup web scraper.  I attached the code below.  Shouldn't my list be a list of ints?

I went through the similar NoneType questions before posting this, but the solutions did not work (or maybe I didn't understand them!)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user-machine/Desktop/cl_phones/main.py", line 47, in <module>
    print "Low: $" + intprices[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Relevant Snippet:

```
intprices = []
newprices = prices[:]
total = 0
for k in newprices:
    total += int(k)
    intprices.append(int(k))

avg = total/len(newprices)

intprices = intprices.sort()

print "Average: $" + str(avg)
print "Low: $" + intprices[0]
print "High: $" + intprices[-1]
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need to keep track of a total; you can simply `sum(intprices)`, and you should do `1.0*sum(intprices)/len(intprices)` to make sure your average has a decimal point.

Comment: There's nothing in your traceback that says that you can't sort it. The problem is when you try to call `intprices[0]` beacuse `intprices` is `None`.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid Thanks, that's a good tip!

Comment: Another good explanation for the very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`intprices.sort()` is sorting in place and returns `None`, while `sorted( intprices )` creates a brand new sorted list from your list and returns it.

In your case, since you're not wanting to keep `intprices` around in its original form simply doing `intprices.sort()` without reassigning will solve your issue.

Comment: Dang, good eye. I had ruled that out, too. Thanks for the tip, that solved it! I'll select as answer as soon as I'm allowed.

Answer (score 15):

Your problem is the line:

`intprices = intprices.sort()`

The `.sort()` method on a list operates on the list in-place, and returns `None`.  Just change it to:

`intprices.sort()`