# .sort() giving me a NonType error for my function

Tags: python, non-type

I'm trying to make a function that gives me the average of a list, excluding the maximum and minimum value. I want to sort my list but when I do, I get a 'NonType' error. Here's my code:

```
def ave_no_max_min(DataList):
    return sum(DataList.sort()[1:-1])/(len(DataList)-2)
print(ave_no_max_min([2,4,3,5,11])) ##should return
```

Comment: `list.sort()` is an in-place operation -- it modifies a `list` without returning it. Doing `print(type([3, 2, 1].sort()))` returns `<class 'NoneType'>`.

Comment: What does `.sort()` return (hint it's not a list).

Comment: Have you done *any* debugging?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Asking the right question. This is two seconds of debugging, and sometimes none (ha) at all, since I think my IDE would catch this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't sort my list because it is NoneType? Simple Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668154/cant-sort-my-list-because-it-is-nonetype-simple-python)

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7301110/11301900

Comment: Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score -1):

The method sort sorts the given list and returns None. So you were applying the list slicing to a NoneType object.

```
def ave_no_max_min(DataList):
    DataList.sort()
    return sum(DataList[1:-1])/(len(DataList)-2)
print(ave_no_max_min([2,4,3,5,11]))
```

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Just working on OP's code @AlexanderCécile

Comment: Of course, but I see no reason why that couldn't be changed, or at the very least mentioned, right?

Comment: As it has no relation with the original issue, no I don't think so