# Python 3 sorting "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, python-3.x

When sorting in Python 3, I get:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Here is my code:

```py
for f in self.db[key].sort():
  yield f
```

I have confirmed none of the items in my list are None.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't sort my list because it is NoneType? Simple Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668154/cant-sort-my-list-because-it-is-nonetype-simple-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "return list.sort()" return None, not the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list)

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted, I have exactly the same situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is simple, Python3 provides two methods and you're using the wrong one,

- `sorted(foo)` returns a copy sorted, uses core `sorted()`.
- `.sort()` sorts the stuff in place, returns None

You need to call `sorted(foo)` instead. For more information see the docs on [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)