# whats the deal with x.sort() and x.reverse()?

Tags: python, list

```
x = [1, 3, 5, 7]
y = [2, 4, 6, 8]
x +=y
x.sort()
print(x.sort())
```

Every time I try to get an output for this python just returns none. Why is this? I also get the same result when I try to use x.reverse() and the like. 
Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html `in-place` meaning it will not return anything and just modify the existing data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list/12699808#12699808 Python doesn't cleanly allow multi-line expressions. For readability purposes, it was decided that functions that modify existing objects should not return the objects after modification.

Answer (score 1):

`x.sort()` sorts the list in place, it returns None, it just modifies the order of the list elements. The same goes for `x.reverse()`

From the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq)

> 7. The sort() and reverse() methods modify the list in place for economy of space when sorting or reversing a large list. To remind you that they operate by side effect, they don’t return the sorted or reversed list.

These two list's functions should not be confused with more general built-in functions [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed). Which are functions (not method) and can be applied to different objects (not only lists) and return a new object.

Now to answer your question specifically, when you do: `print(x.sort()) you're saying "print the returns value of x.sort()" which is None. You can fix your code by doing:

```
x.sort()
print x
```