# comparing sorted lists

Tags: python

Implement a program that requests three words (strings) from the user. Your program should print `True` if the words were entered in alphabetical order; otherwise nothing is printed.

```
Enter first word: bass
Enter second word: salmon
Enter third word: whitefish
True
```

Since `B > S > W`, it prints `True`

This is what I have so far:

```
FirstWords=input("Enter first word: ")

SecondWords=input("Enter second word: ")

ThirdWords=input("Enter third word: ")

word=[FirstWords,SecondWords,ThirdWords]

print(word)

k=word.sort()

print(k)
if (k==None):
    print('True')

elif (word==k):
    print("True")
```

Somehow I cannot store the value of word.sort() in k

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list

Comment: `list.sort` sorts the list in-place and returns `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sorting `word` "in place" (i.e. it sorts `word` directly, it doesn't return a sorted copy) with `word.sort()`. It doesn't return anything useful.

You could use `k=sorted(word)` instead, which returns a sorted copy and doesn't affect `word`.

Comment: It worked smoothly. Thank you very much !