# sort() returns None

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, recursion, return

Code:

```
import math
import time
import random
class SortClass(object):
    def sort1(self, l):
        if len(l)==1:
            return l
        elif len(l)==2:
            if l[0]<l[1]:
                return l
            else:
                return l[::-1]
        else:
            pivot=math.floor(len(l)/2)
            a=l[pivot:]
            b=l[:pivot]
            a2=self.sort1(a)
            b2=self.sort1(b)
            if a2==None or b2==None:
                a2=[]
                b2=[]
            return (a2+b2).sort()
        return []
Sort=SortClass()
x=[20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
print(Sort.sort1(x))
```

The code outputs None even though it should return an empty list in two cases:

```
return []
```

and

```
a2=self.mergeSort(a)
b2=self.mergeSort(b)
if a2==None or b2==None:
    a2=[]
    b2=[]
return (a2+b2).sort()
```

Details:
The code is for a list sorting module I am making for python practice (I am relatively new at python). `sort1` is a modified mergesort.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "return list.sort()" return None, not the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@reut got to it first but

```
return sorted(a2+b2)
```

not

```
return (a2+b2).sort()
```

Additionally

```
if a2 == None or b2 == None:
    a2 = []
    b2 = []
```

Should be

```
if a2 == None:
    a2 = []
if b2 == None:
    b2 = []
```

Your setting both to [] if either is none meaning if a2 is [1] and b2 is none your throwing away a2. I'm guessing this is unintended.

Also in your code you have an uppercase S in the lower sortClass

in addition 
    return[]
will never return, the above else does not allow it to.

Comment: Fixed the grammar/spelling of my post.

Comment: The check for Nones was just because it was returning None but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 8):

[`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) returns `None` (sorts in-place):

```
>>> [].sort() is None
True
```

You're using it here:

```
return (a2+b2).sort()
```

Use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort to a new list and not in-place:

```
return sorted(a2+b2)
```