# how to sort the date list in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list in python as follows..

```
[Timestamp('2016-01-03 10:38:52'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-18 09:37:29'),
 Timestamp('2016-02-06 09:44:44'),
 Timestamp('2016-02-07 11:11:28'),
 Timestamp('2016-02-15 11:24:41'),
 Timestamp('2016-02-20 12:46:07'),
 Timestamp('2016-02-21 11:07:11')]
```

I want to sort this with ascending order

I tried with `temp_list.sort()` but it does not display any output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-or-object-with-sorted-in-python/

Comment: @Arman No, the `sort()` function operates in-place and returns `None`, so your suggestion will override `temp_list` with `None`!

Comment: Note that the example input given is already in ascending order, so sorting it won't change it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`temp_list.sort()` will sort the list *in place*.  That means that it will not return anything.  You can say `x = sorted(y)` to assign `x` to a sorted version of `y`, but you could also say `y.sort()` to define `y` as the sorted version.

Example with `sort`:

```
>>> xx = [2, 1]
>>> xx.sort()
>>> print(xx)
[1, 2]             # xx got sorted
```

and with `sorted`:

```
>>> xx = [2, 1]
>>> sorted_xx = sorted(my_list)
>>> print(sorted_xx)
[1, 2]
>>> print(xx)
[2, 1]             # xx is still unsorted
```

Comment: I didn't get you. sorry new to python

Comment: Lets say you define a list: `x = [4, 5, 2, 3]` and you want to print the sorted version `[2, 3, 4, 5]`.  You could say `y = sorted(x); print(y)`.  That is because `sorted()` returns a sorted version of `x`.  You could also say `x.sort(); print(x)`.  That is because `x.sort()` does not return the sorted list; it just modifys the list so that it is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Python sorts lists in place, meaning there is no return. If you were to look at the value of your list again you will see it sorted in ascending order.