# Extending list copy in one line

Tags: python

When I execute the following:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b':3, 'c': 5}
b = [2,4,6]
c = list(b)
c.extend(a.values())
print c
```

It prints out `[2, 4, 6, 1, 5, 3]` as I expected, but when I try to do the list copy and extension in one line:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b':3, 'c': 5}
b = [2,4,6]
d = list(b).extend(a.values()) 
print d
```

It prints `None`.  Why are these different?

Comment: You're getting the result of `extend()`, which is `None` indeed. `extend()` does not return the list

Comment: @AndreaCorbelliniis right. BTW, why are you explicitly using list(b)? b is already a list?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Thanks, that's right I want to have an unmodified copy of b as well.

Comment: For some more info about what Andrea said see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list

Answer (score 2):

Because `list.extend()` does not return the modified list but operate on the list itself.

I guess you may want to reuse `d`. If you want to create a new `d` to hold the result after extending and do it in one line, try:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b':3, 'c': 5}
b = [2,4,6]
d = list(b) + list(a.values()) 
print d
```

Two points to note:

1. dictionary.value() returns a **view object** but not a plain list
2. values / keys in a default Python dictionary is **randomly ordered**

Comment: @Will Edited, missed the last line of question

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to make the variable `d`. `extend()` will extend the list in place so just use this:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b':3, 'c': 5}
b = [2,4,6]
b.extend(a.values()) 
print b
```

This will give you the desired output: `[2, 4, 6, 5, 3, 1]`

**EDIT:**
According to the OP he wanted `b` to remain unchanged. All you need to do is make a copy of `b` and then extend that. You can do that like this:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b':3, 'c': 5}
b = [2,4,6]
c = b[:]
c.extend(a.values()) 
print c
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I actually want to keep an unmodified copy of b as well. Should I just make a copy right before?

Comment: I updated my answer with the correct code for your application. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

What you assign to `d` variable is the result of the list(b).extend function. This method does not return anything - it extends existing mutable object. list(b) is modified but since you did not save it anywhere the statement won't have any effect.