# python3 'Nontype object' is not subscriptable

Tags: list, python-3.x, return, nonetype

How can I solve this problem?

```
def median(lst):
    lst_s=lst.sort()
    k=len(lst)

    if k%2==0:
        return ((lst_s[k/2]+lst_s[k/2-1])/2)
    elif k%2==1:
        return (lst_s[k/2-1/2])

res = median([1,2,3,7,6,5])
print('median:',res)
```

when I run this, it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\lab5_p4_2015123176.py", line 13, in <module>
    res = median([1,2,3,7,6,5])
  File "E:\lab5_p4_2015123176.py", line 7, in median
    return ((lst_s[k/2]+lst_s[k/2-1])/2)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "return list.sort()" return None, not the list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `list.sort()` sorts the items of the list in place thus returns `None`. In your `median` function you need to replace `lst_s = lst.sort()` by `lst_s = sorted(lst)` if you don't want to modify element order in the original list.