# File search function keeps giving None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, file, filereader

I am testing input/output for a given file. Each file contains strings and I am to search for 's' in that file and return an ordered list of locations of s in that file. I created my function, but I do not know why it keeps returning None. Any thoughts or how to resolve this?

Here is my function:

```
def locate(filename,s):
    lookfor=s
    new_list=[]
    with open(filename) as my_file:
        for line in my_file:
            if lookfor in line:
                new_list.append(line)
        return new_list.sort()
```

Comment: `sort()` works **inplace**. So write two statements: `new_list.sort()` and `return new_list`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "return list.sort()" return None, not the list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list)

Comment: Fixed the duplicate. I did two statements but I am still getting wrong output. See updated questions.

Comment: well you `append(..)` the `line`. So evidently it adds the entire line.

Comment: should I use index to get the location instead of line then?

Comment: Yes, use `append(line.index(s))`.

Comment: Furthermore you only need to `sort` once at the end. So do that **after** the `for` loop.

Comment: Okay so that fixed that issue, however now it is returning incorrect locations.

Comment: @KelseyGreenwood: but what do you mean with *locations*? The column number or the row number?

Comment: list of all line numbers containing s, which is case sensitive

Comment: in that case  the `for` should look like `for num,line in enumerate(my_file):` and you `append(num)` so no index anymore.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem edited to reflect that change, but still gives the wrong number

Comment: @KelseyGreenwood: not that the line numbers are *zero-based*: so the *first* line is `0`. You can change it to `enumerate(my_file,1)` if you want *one-based* line numbers.

Comment: That solved the issue! If you want to make an answer, I'll accept it! @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do these list operations (methods) return None, rather than the resulting list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-do-these-list-operations-methods-return-none-rather-than-the-resulting-li)

Comment: **Please do not edit questions** to apply a fix for one problem and then ask about the next question. If the first problem was due to a duplicate, it should be closed; **start over** with a **new** question. Keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**; the question is **not** there so that people can fix your code, but so that the question can help build a searchable library of questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
def locate(filename,s):
    lookfor=s
    new_list=[]
    with open(filename) as my_file:
        for num, line in enumerate(my_file,1):
            if lookfor in line:
                new_list.append(num)
        new_list.sort()
        return new_list
```