# Numpy fill_diagonal return None

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate symmetric zero diagonal matrices. My symmetric part work, but when I use fill_diagonal from numpy as the result I got  "None". My code is below. Thank you for reading

```
import numpy as np
matrix_size = int(input("Size of the matrix \n"))
random_matrix = np.random.random_integers(-4,4,size=(matrix_size,matrix_size))
symmetric_matrix = (random_matrix + random_matrix.T)/2
print(symmetric_matrix)
zero_diogonal_matrix = np.fill_diagonal(symmetric_matrix,0)
print(zero_diogonal_matrix)
```

Comment: @roganjosh thank you so much for the response. Then, in this case, how can I assign zero value to the dioganal?

Comment: @roganjosh thank you for the response. I have done by this way too. The result is same None again symmetric_matrix = (random_matrix + random_matrix.T)/2
print(np.fill_diagonal(symmetric_matrix,0))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`np.fill_diagonal()`, like many other methods across python/numpy, works in-place. For example: [Why does “return list.sort()” return None, not the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list). That is that it directly alters the object in memory and does not create a new object. The return value from such functions is `None`. Therefore, change:

```
zero_diogonal_matrix = np.fill_diagonal(symmetric_matrix,0)
```

To just:

```
np.fill_diagonal(symmetric_matrix,0)
```

You will then see the change reflected in `symmetric_matrix`.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably overkill, but in case you want to preserve the tenet of minimising surprise, you could wrap this (and other functions like it) in a function that takes care of preserving the original array:

```
def fill_diagonal(source_array, diagonal):
    copy = source_array.copy()
    np.fill_diagonal(copy, diagonal)
    return copy
```

But the question then becomes *"who exactly is going to be least surprised by doing it this way?"*