# Set values on the diagonal of pandas.DataFrame with fill_diagonal()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to set the values of the digonal in a pandas.df. I followed the answer in [Set values on the diagonal of pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475094/set-values-on-the-diagonal-of-pandas-dataframe)

The solution of `df.values[[np.arange(df.shape[0])] * 2] = 0` works fine.

But I wish to use `np.fill_diagonal(df.values, 0)`  which gives AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'flat'

Comment: For me it working nice with sample data `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,5))`, what is your pandas version?

Comment: 0.22.0, I will try to upgrade and see if it solves the problem

Comment: I just check linked solution and working in 2014 year, so problem is something else :(

Comment: I could not upgrade to pandas 0.23.4 since I am not the admin of the computer.  Pyton3 is installed only on my user and not as admin, could that cause the problem somehow?

Comment: tryied to use your sample data `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,5))` and I still get that error

Comment: hmmm, not idea. only idea is use `arr = df.values`, `df = pd.DataFrame(np.fill_diagonal(arr, 0), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)` - working with numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too but solved it when I realised that `np.fill_diagonal()` [works in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445894/numpy-fill-diagonal-return-none).

`np.fill_diagonal(df,0)` gave me the `AttributeError:` you described and `np.fill_diagonal(df.values,0)` returns `None` so if you do something like:

```
df_zeros = np.fill_diagonal(df.values,0)
print(df_zeros)
```

or try to use the result elsewhere it won't work, but if you do:

```
np.fill_diagonal(df.values,0)
print(df)
```

I think you'll see what you're looking for.