# Sorting a list through a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

```
def sortt(n):
     return n.sort()

print([1,5,2,3])
```

it returns `none`.

Even if I try:

```
def sortt(n):
    lst = [ ]
    lst = n.sort()
    return lst

print([1,5,2,3])
```

then also returns `none`.

Comment: Why do you need a function for this? Instead of calling `sort(n)` and having it return `n.sort()` why not just call `n.sort()` in the first place? The only way I could see a sort function being useful is if you had a specific sorting algorithm in mind such as a bubble sort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "return list.sort()" return None, not the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do these list operations (methods) return None, rather than the resulting list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-do-these-list-operations-methods-return-none-rather-than-the-resulting-li)

Answer (score 1):

`lst.sort()` alters `lst` in-place and returns `None`.

`sorted(lst)` returns the sorted list to you while keeping `lst` unchanged.

Using your provided code as a template:

```
def sort1(arr):
    arr.sort()
    return arr

print(sort1([1,5,2,3]))
```

Output:
[1, 2, 3, 5]

```
def sort2(arr):
    return sorted(arr)

print(sort2([1,5,2,3]))
```

Output:
[1, 2, 3, 5]