# Printing a list method return None

Tags: python-3.x

I am an extremely begginer learning python to tackle some biology problems, and I came across lists and its various methods. Basically, when I am running print to my variable I get None as return.

Example, trying to print a sorted list assigned to a variable

```
list1=[1,3,4,2]
sorted=list1.sort()
print(sorted)
```

I receive None as return. Shouldn't this provide me with [1,2,3,4]

However, when printing the original list variable (list1), it gives me the sorted list fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "return list.sort()" return None, not the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Actually, this behaviour and the motivations for it are documented: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort

Comment: Thanks everyone. I thought list will behave similar to strings in a way or another. For example, printing a variable with upper method, will print the expected outcome(the string with uppercase, while the original string remain intact), but apparently this is not the case with lists!

Answer (score 6):

Because the `sort()` method will always return `None`. What you should do is:

```
list1=[1,3,4,2]
list1.sort()
print(list1)
```

Or

```
list1=[1,3,4,2]
list2 = sorted(list1)
print(list2)
```

Comment: Actually `list.sort()` DOES return something (the `None` object).

Comment: Yeah, right. But every function return None if it do not return anything... ex: `def a(): pass` will return None. So can we not admit None is nothing in this case?

Comment: `None` is indeed designed to represent "nothing" in Python, but saying "`list.sort()` returns `None`" is not the same thing as saying "`list.sort()` doesn't return anything" (which is a technical impossibilty in Python anyway). The distinction may seems pedantic from a purely functional POV but it's still important for newcomers to understand it if they are to build a correct mental map of how Python works.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort lists in two ways. Using `list.sort()` and this will sort `list`, or `new_list = sorted(list)` and this will return a sorted list `new_list` and `list` will not be modified.

So, you can do this:

```
list1=[1,3,4,2]
sorted=sorted(list1)
print(sorted)
```

Or you can so this:

```
list1=[1,3,4,2]
list1.sort()
print(list1)
```

Comment: Take care: `list1.sorted()` won't work! You meant `sorted(list1)`

Comment: Typo, sorry. I fix the post.