# Unexpected output of .sort() method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I'm getting a 'None' result when I'm trying to sort a list and returning it to itself, why is that?

performing simply '.sort()' of the list yield the correct output.

```
>>> letters=['b','d','a']

>>> letters=letters.sort()

>>> print(letters)

None
>>> letters=['b','d','a']

>>> letters.sort()

>>> print(letters)

['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Comment: `sort` is sorting the elements in-place. You are just overwritting `letters` with `None`

Comment: The second sentence is the answer for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.sort()` method doesn't return anything. You might be looking for `sorted()`:

```
letters = sorted(letters)
```

Comment: Alright- I found -->  The primary difference between the list sort() function and the sorted() function is that the sort() function will modify the list it is called on. The sorted() function will create a new list containing a sorted version of the list it is given.

Comment: Yep, that's correct. So you probably either want `letters = sorted(letters)` or `letters.sort()`.

Answer (score 0):

yes that is confusing, but I guess it is to make clear, that the list is sorted instead of just returning a sorted copy of the list.

So instead of

```
letters=letters.sort()
```

Just write:

```
letters.sort()
```

The list is sorted in-place. I also think that it would have been better to return self instead of returning nothing in this case, as this would make chaning possible and in some cases you would not even have to assign the list to a variable (e.g. if you call a function and need to pass the list sorted, you could otherwise just make a copy in the function call and call sort on it).

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you’re setting letters to the return value of letters.sort(). But letters.sort() just rearranges the values and does not actually return anything, so you’re storing None.

In the second example, you are doing it correctly, because .sort() is a list method that rearranges the values in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` for your goal.

```
In [1]: letters=['b','d','a']                                                                  

In [2]: letters = sorted(letters)                                                              

In [3]: letters                                                                                
Out[3]: ['a', 'b', 'd']
```

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#sorted

```
list.sort(key=None, reverse=False)
Sort the items of the list in place (the arguments can be used for sort customization, see sorted() for their explanation).
```

list.sort return None

[Why does "return list.sort()" return None, not the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list)