# Why does Python built-in .sort() fail to work in my for-loop?

Tags: python, list, sorting, for-loop

In the following function I wrote in Python 3.6, there is a for-loop with .sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0)) to sort a list. But .sort method failed to work. It only print a "None" to me as a result.

Please give me some advice. Thank you very much.

```
import operator
...

def phrase_similarity(phrase):

phrase_vec = phrase_model[phrase]
CosDisList = []

for a_word in phrase_model.keys():
    a_val = phrase_model[a_word]
    cos_dis = cosine_similarity(phrase_vec, a_val)
    StrPhrase = str( phrase + ":" + a_word)
    CosDisBind = [float(str(cos_dis.tolist()).strip('[[]]')), StrPhrase]
    CosDisList.append(CosDisBind)
    CosDisListSort = CosDisList.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True) #Why .sort() method doesn't work here?

print(CosDisListSort)
```

Comment: `list.sort` does an `inplace` sort, meaning the `list` will be sorted itself and return `None`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why does list.sort return None and not the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list)

Comment: What is the purpose of re-sorting the list every time an element is added? Why not just sort it once, after the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.sort` sorts in-place. It modifies the `list` object it is called on, but it returns `None`. So you should not reassign the return value. Just

```
CosDisList.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
```

will suffice. The built-in [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function will return a sorted list while leaving the passed iterable untouched. There, you would have to assign the result:

```
new_list = sorted(CosDisList, key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
```