# List is not printing in Python

Tags: python

My following code is supposed to collect numeric inputs from the user, put it in a list, and sort them:

```
def build_list():
    """Builds a list by continually collecting input from the user until 'done' is provided."""

    raw_list = []

    while True:

        item = input("Enter a numeric value: ")

        if item.lower() == "done":
            break
        try:
            item = int(item)
        except ValueError:
            print("That wasn't a valid number. Try again or enter 'done' to stop making the list.")
        else:
            raw_list.append(item)

    return raw_list


def sort_list(unsorted_list):
    sorted_list = unsorted_list.sort()
    return sorted_list


def main():
    my_list = build_list()
    my_list = sort_list(my_list)
    print(my_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This piece of code is printing "None" instead of printing my sorted list. What step am I missing here?

Comment: `.sort()` returns None

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7301110/11301900.

Answer (score 3):

The `sort()` fonction (as well as the `reverse()` function) works "in-place" and always return `None`.

You should write:

```py
def sort_list(unsorted_list):
    sorted_list = list(unsorted_list)  # local copy if needed
    sorted_list.sort()
    return sorted_list
```

You can also use the `sorted()` function:

```py
def sort_list(unsorted_list):
    sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list)
    return sorted_list
```

See: [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Answer (score 3):

`sort` sorts a list inplace and returns `None`. Either call `sort` without returning it:

```py
def main():
    my_list = build_list()
    my_list.sort() # Here
    print(my_list)
```

or use `sorted`:

```py
def main():
    my_list = build_list()
    my_list = sorted(my_list) # Here
    print(my_list)
```