# Variables are assigned only locally inside a for loop

Tags: python, kaggle

I am doing the first Kaggle challenge and I am stupified by this behaviour.

combine consists of two pd.DataFrame, one is the training set the other the test set. I wanted to drop two columns so I created a for loop that iterates over the items in combine.

```
for dataset in combine:
    dataset = dataset.drop(['Ticket', 'Cabin'], axis=1)
    print(dataset.columns)
for dataset in combine:
    print(dataset.columns)
```

For some reason, the assignment happens only locally and doing another for loop reveals that the actual data has not changed. The output is as follows.

```
Index(['PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp',
       'Parch', 'Fare', 'Embarked'],
      dtype='object')
Index(['PassengerId', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare',
       'Embarked'],
      dtype='object')
Index(['PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp',
       'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked'],
      dtype='object')
Index(['PassengerId', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch',
       'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked'],
      dtype='object')
```

As you can see, in the second for loop the columns are back. Where is the problem? Am I misunderstanding how the for loop works in Python?

---

edit:

@kaya3 It is not the case with [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
for dataset in combine:  
    dataset['Name'] = dataset['Name'].map(name_map)  
    dataset['Name'] = dataset['Name'].fillna(0)
```

This code changes the original dataFrames in combine. The docs say that it returns series (not None). How do I tell whether the function will mutate the value?

Comment: You dropped the columns from your local copy of the data set.  You never changed the original data sets.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), the `drop` method returns a new dataframe, so it presumably doesn't also mutate the old one.

Comment: @kaya3, so does the new dataframe have the updated table without `Ticket` and `Cabin`...just curious

Comment: Obligatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @chepner thank you for the link. Now it makes clear sense. I was assigning the local variable to a value, rather than mutating the values.

Comment: @kaya3 How do you tell that it is returning a new dataframe? It just says 'DataFrame without the removed index or column labels.'

Comment: Because if it wasn't a new one, there would be no need to return it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7301481/12299000) for example.

Comment: @kaya3 It is not the case with [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

`name_map = {'Mr': 1, 'Mrs':2, 'Miss':3, 'Master':4, 'Rare':5}  
for dataset in combine:  
    dataset['Name'] = dataset['Name'].map(name_map)  
    dataset['Name'] = dataset['Name'].fillna(0)`  

This code changes the original dataFrames in combine. The docs say that it returns series (not None).

Comment: Well if you do `dataset['Name'] = ...` then of course it changes the dataframe. If `map` changed it in-place then you wouldn't need to write `dataset['Name'] = ...`. See this part of chepner's link: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html#presto_chango

Comment: Also this part: *"Note that “i = x” assigns to the name i, but “i[0] = x” doesn’t, it assigns to the first element of i’s value. It’s important to keep straight what exactly is being assigned to."* In your map example, the `dataset['Name'] = ...` mutates the dataset, in the other case `dataset = ...` doesn't mutate the dataset, it just rebinds the local variable named `dataset`.

Comment: You can also see from the docs, *"**inplace bool, default False**
If True, do operation inplace and return None."* So the fact that `inplace` is `False` by default, and you didn't make it `True` explicitly, means the `drop` and the `map` are both not done in-place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in the loop `dataset` is a copy of the DataFrame in combine, so when you change `dataset` you aren't changing the actual DataFrame in `combine`, just the copy. To change the actual  DataFrame in the list try something like this:

```
for ii in range(len(combine)):
    combine[ii] = combine[ii].drop(['Ticket', 'Cabin'], axis=1)
```

Now you are changing the variable in the list and not just the copy.

Comment: Or use the `inplace=True` option  `dataset = dataset.drop(['Ticket', 'Cabin'], axis=1, inplace=True)`