# instance Variable not getting updated

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

why instance vaiable is not getting sorted when i use sort function, the function sort_players_based_on_experience(self) is giving None as o/p.

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, players_list):
        self.__players_list=players_list

    def sort_players_based_on_experience(self) :


        self.__players_list=self.__players_list.sort(key=lambda x:x.get_experience())
        return self.__players_list
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "return list.sort()" return None, not the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do these list operations (methods) return None, rather than the resulting list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-do-these-list-operations-methods-return-none-rather-than-the-resulting-li)

Answer (score 1):

`.sort` is an in-place function, and it doesn't return anything. What you want to do instead is just call `.sort` on the array without reassigning the variable, or use `sorted` which returns the sorted array:

```
def sort_players_based_on_experience(self) :
    self.__players_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.get_experience())
    return self.__players_list
```

or

```
def sort_players_based_on_experience(self) :
    self.__players_list = sorted(self.__players_list, key=lambda x: x.get_experience())
    return self.__players_list
```