# Transpose an image in python using only for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I need to transpose an image in python without using any other import statements or function libraries. The image is being passed as a parameter to my function. The image is a 2-D table of RGB objects. I have the following code but it gives me an index error - list index out of range.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#Find the size of the non-ragged table
numrows = len(image) 
numcols = len(image[0]) # All rows have same no. cols

# Build the table
result = [] # Result accumulator
for m in range(numcols):
    
    # Make a single row
    row = [] # Single row accumulator
    for n in range(numrows):
        row.append(image[n][m])
    
    # Add the result to the table
    result.append(row)
    image.clear()
    image.append(row)
return True
```

Comment: There's a [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473724/4799172) which wouldn't require any imports btw

Comment: Can you show an example starting value for `image` that causes the problem? Actually - what exactly do you think that `image.clear()` line is doing? Does it make sense to have that happen in the place where it is happening? Why?

Comment: My approach seems similar to what some have suggested in that post. Why is my method throwing an error

Comment: Trying to make a transposed copy with the pixels from the original image. Then remove all the rows in the image and replace it with the rows from the transposed copy.

Answer (score 0):

*Each time* through the outer loop, you attempt to *completely erase* `image` and then append the most recently computed `row` to it. But this is your *source* data; the next time through the outer loop, you attempt to build the next row with `row.append(image[n][m])` as if nothing had happened.

You are already using `result` to accumulate the result; don't modify `image` during the process. Not only does it cause the problem you are seeing, but it is bad interface design: the person *using* your code (*which will probably be you, months from now when you have forgotten what you were thinking*) will very definitely *not* expect the value of `image` to change at all when computing the transposed version and giving it a separate name.

You have a list named `result`, and you are apparently doing this inside a function; the natural thing to do would be to `return result`, and **not** modify any of the input data. If for some reason you *had* to modify the input list, then the way to do that is to assign the *contents* of `result` back into the `image` list, a *single* time, *after* all the loops: something like `image[:] = result`. But in this case, there is no good reason to `return` anything; `return True` doesn't mean anything useful (if something went wrong, you should **not** `return False` or *any other value*; you should instead *raise an Exception* - that's what they're for). Since in this case the calling code gets all the information it needs by just using the modified version of `image` after calling the function, the return value is useless. The [standard library also adopts this convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list).

Comment: The ask from my function is that it does not return anything. It needs to modify the image. Are you suggesting, I take it out of the outer loop?

Comment: Thank You Thank You Thank You @Karl Knechtel ! That solved the problem! Its working now. I am new to python and returning to coding after 16 years. Thanks once again! Much appreciated.