# Can I use update method of set in Python to merge two set (x-y) and (y-x)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, symmetric-difference

I have these two source code and I do not understand the difference

```
x = {"apple", "banana", "cherry"}
y = {"google", "microsoft", "apple"}

z = x.symmetric_difference(y)

print(z) ## z now is {'google', 'cherry', 'microsoft', 'banana'}
```

and

```
x = {"apple", "banana", "cherry"}
y = {"google", "microsoft", "apple"}

z = (x - y).update((y - x))

print(z) ## z now is NoneType
```

why the second code does not result in as the first one? as I know, (x-y) will return a set, then I apply update method with (y - x) to merge (x-y) set and (y-x), so the results should be same?

Comment: ``set.update`` is an inplace operation, like ``list.append``. These always return ``None`` in Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does “return list.sort()” return None, not the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list)

Comment: I have got your point, many thanks @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 0):

With a small change it will work:

```
x = {"apple", "banana", "cherry"}
y = {"google", "microsoft", "apple"}

z = x - y
z.update((y - x))

print(z)
```

> {'google', 'cherry', 'microsoft', 'banana'}

Update operation is in-place, so for the expression you use `x-y` ends up being temporary set value which is updated in-place. Therefore, assignment ends up being `None`.

Comment: Also `z = (x-y) | (y-x)` of `z = (x-y).union(y-x)`.

Answer (score 0):

As @MisterMiyagi said, The update function is in place operation. You can save (x - y) in some variable and you can perform the update operation. Something like this.

```
var = (x - y)
var.update((y - x))
```