# Compare and Merge two lists in python

Tags: python, list, merge

I have two lists. I want to merge the two lists.

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i']
```

The output i want is

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

I have tried the following algorithm

```
missing_elem = []
missing_index = []
elem_to_add = []

for i, elem in enumerate(list_2):
    if elem not in list_1:
        missing_elem.append(elem)
        missing_index.append(i)

print(missing_index)
print(missing_elem)

for i in range(len(missing_index)):
    elem_to_add.append(missing_elem[i])
    list_1.insert(missing_index[i], col_to_add)
    elem_to_add = []
    
print(list_1)
```

The output of above is

```
[3]
['e']
['a', 'b', 'c', ['e'], 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

As e is between 'd' and 'f' in list_2 but in output i am getting it between 'c' and 'd'
Please help me to get correct output

Comment: What is the algorithm meant to do?

Comment: no i dont want to do it using sort. i want order based on previous and next element.
because the actual problem i am working on has some names instead of alphabet

Comment: What if the letters are unsorted? What if there are duplicate letters in one or both lists? Spec seems unclear.

Comment: @ggorlen yes letters are unsorted and no duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, so what does the output look like in the unsorted case? You can trivially get the result you want with `sorted(set(list_1) | set(list_2))` but I suspect this isn't what you want.

Comment: @ggorlen In output add elements based on previous and next elements

Comment: I don't understand that. Sorry. Your existing attempt loops over the entire output set and there's nothing in the description about adjacent elements only. Maybe add input that shows why `sorted(set(list_1) | set(list_2))` _doesn't_ work.

Comment: @ggorlen As e is between 'd' and 'f' in list_2 but in output i am getting it between 'c' and 'd'. so by comparing previous and next element we want to insert it at right index

Comment: Then just sort the output...?

Comment: @ggorlen replace 'e' with 'zebra' , d with cat and f with dog . now  As e is between 'd' and 'f' in list_2 but in output i am getting it between 'c' and 'd'. so by comparing previous and next element we want to insert it at right index

Comment: By what logic do you define "the right index"? Why should "zebra" go between "cat" and "dog"? I strongly recommend editing your post to show 2-3 additional examples that illustrate  your specification. I suggest using lists of elements that aren't alphabetical to better motivate why my suggested solution isn't appropriate. I'm going to tap out because I'm lost and probably just annoying you at this point.

Comment: @ggorlen e is between d  and f in list_2 so it must be in output also

Comment: That makes sense, but what about `a = [1, 5, 3, 15, 2]`, `b = [6, 1, 10]`. What is the correct output? We know we need to insert 6 in `a` but looking at adjacent elements tells us nothing. You said the lists are unsorted. How about `a = [1, 6, 22, 4]`, `b = [7, 2]`?

Comment: the input i am giving have 80 % same elements of list. and in same order except missing values

Comment: OK, thanks. I'd [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68819492/edit) that sort of thing into the post because it's pretty important. Please clearly specify the legal inputs.

Comment: Its seems to me that you are looking for a kind of merge based on current order, not sort order. But then, you have to take arbitrary decision, if you don't want / can not relie on sort order. Especially when having to insert both sides (because both "current" entries are absent from the other side), which side do you insert first ?

Comment: In your current code, col_to_add is undefined.

Comment: I guess, it is element_to_add (that should be elements_to_add as it could harvest more than one item). And so, don't use insert, but a splice as in list_1[3:1] = element_to_add.

Comment: @Sourabh Mittal You give an example of code without even mentioning that it is not working... but you said that you got an output. How is it possible? The problem is that when you want to insert you overwrite that position so need to slice the list each time. And, make clear what you want and provide some understandable description... which ordering criteria? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, building on your efforts:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'b2', 'd', 'f', '1g', 'h', 'i']
list_2 = ['e4', 'z', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'code', 'e', 'e2', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'j']

print(list_1)

# Locate the missing elements in list_1 and their left neighbors
missing_elem_and_neighbor = []
for ind, elem in enumerate(list_2):
    if elem not in list_1:
        if ind > 0:
            missing_elem_and_neighbor.append((elem, list_2[ind-1]))
        else:
            missing_elem_and_neighbor.append((elem, None))

# Insert missing elements into list_1
for elem, nei in missing_elem_and_neighbor:
    if nei:
        ind_nei = list_1.index(nei)
        list_1.insert(ind_nei+1, elem)
    else:
        if list_1[0] in list_2:
            # Goes before 0 in list_1
            list_1.insert(0, elem)
        else:
            # Assumption - right after the first in list_1
            list_1.insert(1, elem)

print(list_1)
```

I made the test case more representative - it's not in alphabetical order to avoid confusion, it has consecutive missing values, and it also starts with missing values.

Instead of finding the missing values, this code also finds their left neighbors. Then it inserts the missing value based on the position of the left neighbor in `list_1`, which preserves the order.

If the missing values occur before the first element of `list_1`, they are just inserted at the beginning of `list_1` in the order they occur in `list_2`. If the first element in `list_1` is altogether missing from `list_2` then `list_2` values end up inserted from index 1 on in `list_1` (check with `list_1 = ['e4', 'z', 'c', 'd', 'code', 'e', 'e2', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'j']`).

To avoid a `ValueError` in case of consecutive missing elements the missing elements are inserted directly into `list_1`, left to right (this can be done with a separate list too, of course, the point is the left-to-right order of insertion, so that the neighbor always exists in the merged list).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a set to get all the unique entries, and then sort it alphabetically.

```
combined = sorted(list(set(list1 + list2)))
```

Comment: `.sort()` is in-place and returns `None`, which is what `combined` ultimately is. You want `sorted()`. And, anyway, I don't think this is what OP really wants (although what they do want is unclear to me).

Comment: I do not agree with @ggorlen. It seems what the OP wants is two things for it's output list : no redundacy & sorting. For no reduncancy : no need ton reinvent the wheel, sets are perfect for that. And using built-in sorted function of python is straight forward too. No extra library, one line, explicit : pythonic.

Comment: @Osamoele If you look at the edits, this post originally used `combined = stuff.sort()` which is [_always wrong_ because `combined` will always be `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list). This answer was then edited to fix that problem, so my comment is partially outdated.

Comment: @Osamoele That said, OP hasn't created a workable specification. All of the answers are random guesses as to OP's intent. If you think this solution works for some problem you have or imagine OP has, that's fine, but it doesn't answer OP's fundamental question even though it happens to produce the right output on their poorly-chosen test case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the rules you want are:

1. Add element from first list to final list if it is not already there
2. Add element from second list to final list if it is not already there

If so, the algorithm is pretty straightforward

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i']

longest_list_len = max(len(list_1), len(list_2))
final_list = []
for i in range(longest_list_len):
    if i < len(list_1):
        elem_1 = list_1[i]
        if elem_1 not in final_list:
            final_list.append(elem_1)
    if i < len(list_2):
        elem_2 = list_2[i]
        if elem_2 not in final_list:
            final_list.append(elem_2)
print(final_list)
> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Comment: This assumes there is only 1 consecutive missing element. `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, `[6, 7, 8]` => `[1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4]`? Are you sure this is the correct result? `[0, 1, 2, 10, 11]`, `[5, 10, 11, 2, 1, 6]` => `[0, 5, 1, 10, 2, 11, 6]`?

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what you're trying to do in the example code but I don't know if it does what you ultimately want to do:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i']


for i in range(len(list_2)):
    if list_2[i] not in list_1:
        list_1.insert(i + 1 , list_2[i])

print(list_1)
>>>['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

What others are asking about exactly what you mean by where the values are "supposed" to go only makes sense to people. We know that "e" goes between "d" and "f" but computers **don't** (outside of sort of course)

there are a lot of ways to tell the computer what the list is supposed to be.
You could have a master list:

```
masterlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', '1', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

And then compare your lists to your master list.

Comment: This also assumes 1 missing element. You could keep track of where you are in the list but ultimately this isn't what OP is trying to do (I don't think).