# Even when I have the return value, it still returns none? Python Code

Tags: python-3.x

The goal of this code is to alphabetize and uppercase the inputted tuple of values. However, it is returning none when I run it. I find this odd since I have a return and I beilieve everything is in correct order. If you can help find the answer, thanks. Here is the code:

```
def sorter(*args):
  args = " ".join(args)
  uppercased = args.upper()
  listed = list(uppercased)
  
  sorted1 = listed.sort()
  return sorted1

print(sorter('happy', 'apple', 'zain', 'freindly', 'jakob'))
```

Comment: what makes you believe that `sort` has a return value?

Comment: have you try using a debugger?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "return list.sort()" return None, not the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list)

Comment: Will suggestion to do these way instead: ```def sorter(*args):
    uppered = [w.upper() for w in args];
    listed = sorted(uppered);
    return listed```

Comment: This should instead have been a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/. Please search for duplicates when closing questions.

Answer (score 2):

Run your code in the [Python Tutor Visualizer](https://pythontutor.com/render.html) and step through it line by line, and you will see that `listed.sort()` doesn't return anything but instead mutates `listed`:

**[Before executing `listed.sort()`](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=def%20sorter%28*args%29%3A%0A%20%20args%20%3D%20%22%20%22.join%28args%29%0A%20%20uppercased%20%3D%20args.upper%28%29%0A%20%20listed%20%3D%20list%28uppercased%29%0A%20%20%0A%20%20sorted1%20%3D%20listed.sort%28%29%0A%20%20return%20sorted1%0A%0Aprint%28sorter%28%27happy%27,%20%27apple%27,%20%27zain%27,%20%27freindly%27,%20%27jakob%27%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=6&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false):**

[image: Before]

**[After executing `listed.sort()`](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=def%20sorter%28*args%29%3A%0A%20%20args%20%3D%20%22%20%22.join%28args%29%0A%20%20uppercased%20%3D%20args.upper%28%29%0A%20%20listed%20%3D%20list%28uppercased%29%0A%20%20%0A%20%20sorted1%20%3D%20listed.sort%28%29%0A%20%20return%20sorted1%0A%0Aprint%28sorter%28%27happy%27,%20%27apple%27,%20%27zain%27,%20%27freindly%27,%20%27jakob%27%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=7&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false):**

[image: After]

The [docs for `list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) also tell you that the list is sorted **in-place**, and the function signature doesn't have a return value.

The solution is therefore to use `listed` after sorting it, instead of creating a new variable `sorted1`.

(Note that there are other logical mistakes in your code which will prevent it from delivering the result you probably expected, even after this specific issue is fixed, but that's beyond the scope of this question and answer.)

Comment: It's great explanations and diagram.   Did a similar diagram recently in one of S/O... it's great for learning debugging.  In earlier days... ;-)