# How would you sort nested arrays in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

How can you sort arrays within an array in Python, ideally without an external library?

I have:

`x = [[0,-1],[0,2],[7,4],[1,5],[6,3],[2,6]]`

and I want to sort every `x[i]`
so eventually I want to get:

`x = [[-1,-0],[0,2],[4,7],[1,5],[3,6],[2,6]]`

Comment: Why should `[4,7]` come before `[1,5]`?

Comment: Oh, you mean you want to sort each sublist. So... just use `.sort()` on each!?

Comment: `[sorted(i) for i in x]`

Comment: I tried `x = [i.sort() for i in x]` but it just returned None values. I don't really get why

Comment: [Why does "return list.sort()" return None, not the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a comprehension and sort each sublist:

```
>>> [sorted(i) for i in x]
[[-1, 0], [0, 2], [4, 7], [1, 5], [3, 6], [2, 6]]
```

Functional programming style:

```
>>> list(map(sorted, x))
[[-1, 0], [0, 2], [4, 7], [1, 5], [3, 6], [2, 6]]
```

**Note**: `sort` is in place while `sorted` returns a copy

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
x = [[0,-1],[0,2],[7,4],[1,5],[6,3],[2,6]]
for obj in x:
    obj.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might us `map` to apply `sorted` to each element following way

```
x = [[0,-1],[0,2],[7,4],[1,5],[6,3],[2,6]]
x = list(map(sorted,x))
print(x)
```

gives output

```
[[-1, 0], [0, 2], [4, 7], [1, 5], [3, 6], [2, 6]]
```