My reverse list function just prints a "none" when I run it
This is my list:
my_list = ['apple', "banana", "cherry", "date", "elderberry"]
def reverse_list(theList):
    newList = theList
    inverseList = newList.reverse()
    return inverseList

print(my_list)
print(reverse_list(my_list))

The output is
['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date', 'elderberry']
None
Have to return a new list with the reversed elements of the old list, without changing the old list

reverse is an in-place function: it returns nothing, it modifies the list. return newList

Oh oops, that should’ve been https://stackoverflow.com/q/7301110/364696

newList = theList This does not make a new copy of the list, as you seem to expect.  It only creates a new name for the existing list.

The .reverse() method does not return anything (or in other words: it returns None). It modifies the list in place. So what you need to do is to create a copy first, modify the copy, and return the copy. Like this:
def reverse_list(theList):
    newList = theList.copy()
    newList.reverse()
    return newList


Or just: def reverse_list(theList): return list(reversed(theList))

Or even theList[::-1].
